# Continuous integration with Laravel package and Behat

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, travis-ci, behat

I'm developing a package for Laravel which actually needs the whole Laravel application to run the tests I wrote with Behat.

I'm using Travis as a CI service and I wonder if there is a specific `.travis.yml` configuration to let the tests created for my package run with a newly created Laravel application.

Basically my package consists in a trait for console commands that cannot be tested without installing Laravel itself.

I know I can install a new Laravel application by setting the `install` hook in `.travis.yml` but then I don't know how to integrate and run my tests with the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm gonna share with you my travis config file (I am using Laravel 5.1).

My file works with PHPUnit however just replace the line that runs PHPUnit with your Behat command, everything else is perfect.

**.travis.yml**

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.5.9
  - 5.6
  - 7.0
  - hhvm

matrix:
    allow_failures:
        - php: hhvm

before_script:
- cp .env.travis .env
- mysql -e 'create database homestead;'
- composer self-update
- composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction --dev
- php artisan migrate
- php artisan db:seed

script: vendor/bin/phpunit
```

You must include **.env.travis** as well, a sample file would look like this:

```
APP_ENV=testing
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=xXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxX

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=array
SESSION_DRIVER=array
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

you can of course use specific `DB_CONNECTION` that probably runs with sqlite in memory or so..